# Compare string with integer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to compare a string with an integer and if it meets the given requirement then it would add that value to a text file.

```
test="$fqdn:$port"

if [ $test = "$fqdn:443" ]; then
  echo "$test" | tee -a list.txt
fi
```

In this case the variable `fqdn` would hold the value of a website and port would hold different port numbers but i only want to keep the ones that have a port of 443 after the `:` and append it to a new text file called `list.txt`.

When I run this code I dont get the desired result for some reason. Can someone help? I am very new to programming in shell.

**EDIT:**

The values for the fqdn look like this:

```
something1.awesome.com
something2.awesome.com
something3.awesome.com
something4.awesome.com
something5.awesome.com
...
```

For the ports, it looks like this:

```
80
8090
443
1090
80
80
...
```

**EDIT 2:**

I did think about comparing only the $port with 443 but that wouldn't work in my case because the first fqdn goes with the first port and if the first fqdn:port equals something like fqdn:443 then add it to a text file.

Comment: What is the value of $fqdn and $port in the case that doesn't give the desired output?

Comment: It would be simpler to simply test for "$port" = "443" instead.

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case because the first fqdn goes with the first port and if the first fqdn:port. If it equals something like fqdn:443 then add it to a text file.

Comment: Right before your `if` statement, try adding something like `echo "\$test='$test'; \$fqdn:443='$fqdn:443'"`. This should make it instantly clear what the difference is between `$test` and `$fqdn:443`.

Comment: @bloodstorm17 I don't understand what you're trying to say with that. If the first `fqdn` goes with the first `port`, what's the problem? If you're using the `port` variable to create the `test` string there's no reason it wouldn't work. And if in the final script you won't have that `port` variable you can still use `${test##*:}` to extract the port number.

Comment: Okay so the thing is that i have a list of fqdns and a list of port numbers. They go hand in hand because the first fqdn in the first list goes with the first port in the second list. Now all i really want is for the ones with the 443 ports to be stored else where in a different text file. In the given example above, the only thing that should go into the list.txt file is "something3.awesome.com:443"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if [ $port -eq 443 ]; then
    echo $fqdn:$port | tee -a list.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to treat the combined FQDN and PORT data as SOCKETs and since you also want to log this information, that is preferable. Performing a simple text match with `grep` will then find each row corresponding to a particular port.

Is the socket list available earlier in your script, eg as a list in a file? If so, the following will work (assumes one item per line in the file `socket.txt`):-

```
PORT=443
grep ":$PORT\$" socket.txt | tee -a list.txt
```

Here, grep is searching the file for all strings where the full port number follows a colon. Alternatively, grep will also filter lines passed to it via a pipe.

If you don't have the socket information available, you can combine successive FQDN and PORT items yourself and produce the `socket.txt` file. The following script (eg named `socket`) will do this, provided you can write the FQDN list and PORT list to two files, (again, one item per line).

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
    echo "$*" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ $# = 2 ] || die "usage: `basename $0` FQDN PORT"

exec 6<$1 || die "Cannot open $1"
exec 7<$2 || die "Cannot open $2"

while true
do
    read FQDN <&6 && read PORT <&7 || exit
    echo "$FQDN:$PORT"
done
```

Run as: `socket fqdn.txt port.txt`